# XML Editor supporting XML Schema 1.1

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd, xsd-1.1

Can somebody suggest an opensource **XML editor/eclipse plugin** which supports **xml-schema-1.1** specification.
Basically, I need it to validate the XML against the XSD *on-the-fly*, just like in eclipse.

Comment: I suppose that you mean **XML Schema 1.1**. There is also **XML 1.1**.

Comment: Yes I want to use the new <xs:assert> tags of XML schema 1.1

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't Eclipse have a built-in support for that? If you don't want eclipse, try sublime text editor, or notepad++

Comment: Hi Elchin, thanks for your answer, but as per the following link its still an open issue in Eclipse :https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312163

Comment: I have notepad++, but how can I validate my XML 1.1 on-the-fly with it?

Comment: Install XML Tools plugin, however im not sure if it validates on fly (